# Javascript localStorage to display in reverse order

Tags: javascript

```js
function createItem() {
  localStorage.setItem("test_11", "Lorem ipsum_21");
  localStorage.setItem("test_12", "Lorem ipsum_22");
  localStorage.setItem("test_16", "Lorem ipsum_253");
  localStorage.setItem("test_14", "Lorem ipsum_24");
}

function readValue() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("reports");
  // Get ALL local storage items within the browser using key value pair
  for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    ele.innerHTML += (key + " => " + value) + "\n";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>The set the local Storage</h1>
<button onclick="createItem()">Set session storage item</button>
<h2>Get the value</h2>
<p>Click the button to get the item value:</p>
<button onclick="readValue()">Get the item value</button>
<br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" id='reports'>
 </textarea>
```

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve in readValue can you explain that one also. It will be helpful to give a solution if you add your expected output also

Comment: i'm storing in localStorage as Input below and i want to display in reverse order as output below 


input Data
test_11 => Lorem ipsum_21
test_12 => Lorem ipsum_22
test_16 => Lorem ipsum_2563
test_14 => Lorem ipsum_24

My output to display as below 

test_14 => Lorem ipsum_24
test_16 => Lorem ipsum_2563
test_12 => Lorem ipsum_22
test_11 => Lorem ipsum_21

Comment: added the answer so the last element will be printed first. Check the solution and let me know if any doubts you have

Answer (score 1):

you can reverse the order by making a small change in the forloop. change  i = localStorage.length  and len = 0 and making condition to greater than and instead of incrementing you can decrement it

see below snippet

```
for (var i = localStorage.length, len = 0; i > len; i--) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    console.log(key , value)
  }
```

Comment: @user10540420 Welcome, please accept it. so later if someone checks they will be easy to find the solution. happy coding :)